# What is the difference between dired-tree-up and dired-up-directory?

Tags: emacs

It took me a while to figure out how to go up a directory in dired.  If I run `dired-tree-up`, I get the following error:

> dired-tree-up: Cannot go up to
>   /home/jason/src/ - not in this tree

But if I use `dired-up-directory`, it takes me to the appropriate directory.  Does `dired-tree-up` do something completely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**dired-up-directory**

> Run Dired on parent directory of current directory.
>   Find the parent directory either in this buffer or another buffer.
>   Creates a buffer if necessary.

**dired-tree-up**

> Go up ARG levels in the dired tree.

The main difference between the two is one acts upon a dired-tree, the other upon a directory.  A dired tree is made when you visit multiple directories which are connected to each other.  The dired-tree up will work if you have previously visited that parent directory and haven't killed off that buffer.  The dired-up-directory should always work since it acts upon the directory itself, think of it as doing a 'find-file on $PWD/..'.